# Getting 400 Bad Request Errors using Invoke-RestMethod for Microsoft Cognitive API

Tags: powershell, azure-cognitive-services

we're trying to test and evaluate the Text Analysis API from Microsoft's Cognitive service. We're trying to get the quick and dirty PowerShell script using Invoke-RestMethod to work. After some tweaks we're still getting 400 errors returned to us. We're unsure of what is wrong because the JSON appears to be corrected and the API key we've entered appears to be correct. We've made use of what we found on another person's blog about the use of the additional headers and tried some variants but still no dice. Can someone do a sanity check for us?

```
#html tag stripper function
function htmlStrip ($results)
    {
    #using .NET toString method to ensure PS doesn't interpret same var incorrectly
    $results = $results.toString()
    $results -replace '<[^>]*(>|$)'
    }


Try
{


    [string]$sourceUrl = Read-Host "Enter a URL such as https://foobar.com"
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host "URL requires http:// or https:// prefix e.g. https://cnn.com"
}


$webClient = New-Object Net.WebClient
[string]$results = $webClient.DownloadString($sourceUrl)


[string]$cleanResults = htmlStrip $results


$body = 
[ordered]@{"documents" = 
    @{ "language" = "en"; "id" = $sourceUrl; "text" = $cleanResults }
    }

#>

$body = [ordered]@{
    "documents" = 
    @(
        @{ "language" = "en"; "id" = $sourceUrl; "text" = $cleanResults }
    )
}

$jsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json

#Begin Text Analytics API Call with Invoke-RestMethod wrapper
#[string]$apiUrl = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/keyPhrases"
[string]$apiKey = "REDACTED"


$headers = @{ "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = $apiKey }

$analyticsResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody -ContentType "application/json"  -ErrorAction Stop

Write-Host $analyticsResults

Write-Host $jsonBody
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you put into the `text` property of your request is probably not valid.
I tried your script with a fix URL to the README.md of the TypeScript repo on GitHub and it works.

**Your script (slightly shortened)**

```
$sourceUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/master/README.md'

$webClient = New-Object Net.WebClient
$results = $webClient.DownloadString($sourceUrl)

$body = [ordered]@{
    "documents" = 
    @(
        @{ "language" = "en"; "id" = $sourceUrl; "text" = $results }
    )
}

$jsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json

$apiUrl = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/keyPhrases"
$apiKey = "..."

$headers = @{ "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = $apiKey }

$analyticsResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody -ContentType "application/json"  -ErrorAction Stop
$analyticsResults.documents.keyPhrases
```

**Result**

```
TypeScript compiler
gulp tests
g typescript
TypeScript source
built compiler
TypeScript users
g gulp
TypeScript directory
cd TypeScript
gulp baseline
gulp lint
gulp local
gulp clean
gulp runtests-browser
gulp LKG
Install Gulp tools
...
```

Comment: I see, well thanks for sharing! Maybe Microsoft is prohibiting certain types of printable or non printable characters. Possibly anti-sql injection type chars. Thanks so much for validating for us!